# Retrofit response is not found

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

if status code is 404, in postman i can get for the response, but in android response is null. else if status code is 200 in android i can get for the response

**Code 404**

[image: Code 404 in Postman]

[image: Code 404 in Android]

**Code 200**

[image]

Comment: please include your code, not screenshots of your code

Comment: `body` is for _successful_ responses. use `errorBody` to get the content of the error message. See the documentation: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html (The obvious reason for that is that the `body` object is deserialized, which makes no sense for any non-2xx response)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DTO `UserLoginResponse` not match with the request response. Pls check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Object and you are passing formData... that's why

try below code.. maybe it will help you..

```
HashMap<String, String> meMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put("email","j@rgmail.com");
meMap.put("password","Jp123?");
```